# Finding good parameters for topic modeling using LDA and spacy

Tags: topic-model, lda

I have a data set of customers with n complaints [c_1,...,c_n].
As a result, I want to perform topic modelling to find topics that customers talk about in their complaints. For this I use **LDA** from **spacy**.

Since you don't know in advance how many topics there are and how good the LDA result is, I looked for measures to evaluate LDA.

I used the **u_mass** and **c_v**.

u_mass usually gives me a falling curve the more topics I enter as parameters, the values are between -2 and -3.

c_v gives me different values depending on the number of topics and I can use the elbow method to select some.
I have seen that the c_v values depend strongly on the two parameters "**iterations**" and "**passes**". I have read that c_v should be at least 0.5 to be considered reasonably good. I have noticed that I only achieve values in the range of 0.5 if I specify relatively high values for the two parameters "iterations" and "passes".

Are there any best practices on how to choose the parameters?